Interview Question - looking for better performance solutions
I just had an interview with a startup company in Python, and I'm looking for a better solutions than mine... (I had 15 min to come with the solution).

comment - what is better? I assume the interviewer aimed for better performance.

The question is:
You get a list of lists of strings, for example:  lst = [['id_2','id_3'],['id_3','id_4','id_2'],['id_5']]
The answer you should return is how many connections each string has.
In our example in the first list id_2 connected with id_3. in the second list id_2 connected with id_3 and with id_4.
Therefor the expected solution is {id_2:2, id_3:2 , id_4:2 , id_5:0}
My solution is as follows:
lst = [['id_2','id_3'],['id_3','id_4','id_2'],['id_5']]

#Answer:- {id_2:2, id_3:2 , id_4:2 , id_5:0}
class sln:
  def __init__(self, lst: list):
    self._data = {} # key: id_X, value: list of connections [id_y, id_z]
    self._build_data(lst)

  def count_relations(self):
    result = {}
    for entry in self._data:
      result[entry] = len(self._data[entry])
    return result

  def _build_data(self, lst: list):
    for outter_lst in lst:
      for item in outter_lst:
        if item not in self._data.keys():
          self._data[item] = []
        self._append_relevant_keys(item, outter_lst)

  def _append_relevant_keys(self, item: str, outter_lst: list):
    for entry in outter_lst:
      if entry not in self._data[item] and item != entry:
        self._data[item].append(entry)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(sln(lst).count_relations())

I did mention that I could the lists inside the data object with dictionaries to improve access speed even more.

Can you clarify specifically on what metric you are evaluating solutions as “better” than the one you currently have? Without doing so your question is open to a lot of opinion and interpretation, which is generally considered off topic here (see [help/on-topic])

Why is id_4 2? Just because it's part of the second set that's connected to the first set by the other two entries even though there's no id_4 in the first set? Is two the number of connections between sets, or the number of sets in each connected group? (Though in the latter case I'd expect id_5 to be 1.)

Observe that the order or relationships of the elements is unimportant. If they are a member of a list with more than one element, they participate in a connection.

@esqew what is "better" that is a good question.
I have no idea what are the key factors for the interviewer. I assume the main one is performance.
As someone that interviewed as well I would look for code that is easy to maintain. But as you said it is an open question.

Better is subjective, but IIUC you could loop through the lists and populate a dict of str->set, then get the length of the sets:
d = {}

for l in lst:
    for e in l:
        d.setdefault(e, set()).update([i for i in l if i != e])

d = {k: len(v) for k, v in d.items()}

{'id_2': 2, 'id_3': 2, 'id_4': 2, 'id_5': 0}


I'm guessing the interviewer aimed for a solution as you provided. although I find the code is less readable
